# VB.NET - Fundamental difference of calling .Show() from a Form type and a new instance of the form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, new-operator

Following code is in VB.Net; don't know if the same applies to C#. But suppose I have a `Form` named `Form1`. These two methods appear to produce the same result:

```
' This
Form1.Show()

' and this
Dim form As New Form1
form.Show()
```

What are the differences? (I'm sure there are...)

Comment: Litterally that you're showing a new instance of the form. There will be no link between the two.

Comment: Related: [vb.net auto instantiation (forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18000482/1115360).

Comment: That Form1.Show() works is a pretty sad compatibility feature that only exists in vb.net to help programmers port old vb6 code.  Part of the My.Forms plumbing.  Very hard to unlearn and a major obstacle to learning proper objected-oriented programming.  Also heavily gets in the way when vb.net programmers have to write threaded code.  No equivalent for it in C#, makes porting programs very difficult.  Strongly avoid it.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree it's sad. Thankfully we use C#. Although I hope VB retires that feature soon.