# VB Forms don't recognize each other in the same project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-10

Hi everyone I need some help,
I am having a weird situation every time I try to call a window form I get this error

> BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

I was originally working on Visual Studio 2010 when the first time contouring this problem so I thought that I may accidentally deleted or edited some code in the declaration of the form witch caused the problem so I closed the solution and created a new one to make sure that the problem is limited the solution not to VS. then I add window form "Form2" then created/added a button1 on Form1 to call Form2.Show()
simple code that should work fine but when I tape Form2.Show() it give that ERROR and red mark Form2

so I uninstalled VS2010 then Reset Windows 10 with option to wipe out all data on windows partition (I now that was extreme but I suspected that maybe the system was infected with some virus "prior action") so after that I checked the system with HitmanPro and found nothing then I installed VS2019 Community and get The some problem I searched on the web but did not found any similar case so here I am hoping that someone will resolve the mystery.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 is empty form I didn't make any change on it

Before this problem showing up everything work fine now even old project have the same issue

Thanks

Edit: Add project as simple
https://mega.nz/file/FgoXkCwA#ootxYrXGnR6sQR_Pifjvz617-r_Az1ozXWB49oGxqKU
the project dose not contain any executable file

Comment: You need to have a reference to an instance of Form2 before calling Show(). You are showing us nowhere near enough information to help you. What do you think Form2 refers to? We need to see much more code.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock VB.NET has form auto-instantiation, e.g. one user wanted to disable that feature: [vb.net auto instantiation (forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000482/vb-net-auto-instantiation-forms).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Never knew that.  What a weird feature!

Comment: Does Form2 have a constructor with a parameter? Public Sub New(someThing as someType)?

Comment: thanks to all replies as I mention it I didn't change anything in the auto-generated code of the forms declaration (InitializeComponent, Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form, ..) are normally in Partial Class and I did check/confirmed that they exist that why I don't now what happening one more odd thing is that I can't create .NET 3.5 or 4.* new project on VS2019 (they don't show up in VS2019) could this be the problem? (my old projects are using .Net 3.5 and 4.5)

Comment: What happens if you write `dim f2 as new Form2() f2.Show()`? Does it open? And if you write `My.Forms.Form2.Show()`? Or, e.g., `Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Info.OSPlatform)`: do you see something squiggly there?

Comment: @Jimi thanks it work fine when I use dim f2 as new Form2() f2.Show() but when I try My.Forms.Form2.Show() it give an ERROR BC30456 'Forms' is not a member of 'WinFormsApp1.My' and for Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Info.OSPlatform) give the same ERROR 'Computer' is not a member of 'WinFormsApp1.My and when I tape My. the auto-complete show only one option  "InternalXmlHelper". This is really weird. I have created an New project using .Net 5 and Form2.Show() work as normal. 
I'm really lost, what would cause such behavior

Comment: It's not weird, .Net 5 doesn't support `My`. Not yet, at least. You cannot count on the `My` services. Thus, also the Form Factory is not available. Use the standard OOP form: `dim variable as New Type()`, or `dim variable as Type = New Type()`. In this case: `dim f2 as new Form2() f2.Show()`. I suggest to get used to the normal form and don't use default instances of your Forms ever again.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi yes that exactly what I'm Planning to do, and I'm considering dropping anything related to Microsoft and rewrite all my old project into an other language c++ or java it will be a bit harder for some tasks but I have to deal with it, originally I was using vb just by lazyness

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this when calling a subform:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

' using a Using block:
    Using form2 as New Form2
        form2.ShowDialog(Me)
        form2.Close()
    End Using

' using a With block
    With New Form2
        .ShowDialog(Me)
        .Close()
    End With

End Sub
```

`ShowDialog(Me)` keeps the subform open until a `DialogResult` is provided by the user (`OK` or `Cancel` usually).